# Spring Boot Data Flow : Page Size must not be less than one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to register App to Spring Boot Data Flow local Server. But I am getting following error : on the dashboard.

> Page Size must not be less than one

How to fix this issue? Am I missing any dependency? However, the app is successfully registered from Data Flow Shell. But, still it's not available from the dashboard. See below screenshots and stack trace.

[image]

[image]

```
2017-06-26 12:45:42.314 ERROR 5444 --- [nio-9393-exec-6] o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice         : Caught exception while handling a request

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page size must not be less than one!
    at org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractPageRequest.<init>(AbstractPageRequest.java:47) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest.<init>(PageRequest.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.addPaginationLinks(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:222) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.createResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.web.PagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(PagedResourcesAssembler.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.AppRegistryController.list(AppRegistryController.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being addressed via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#1545](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/1545). The fix will be included in the upcoming [1.2.2.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/milestone/23).

In the meantime, please pull the PR and build it locally for your testing.